# Compiler don't see main method

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

Compiler don't see main method and I can't run program, maybe the problem is because I set main method in the last child class? I have father class Nasleđivanje, child class Panel1 which extends Nasleđivanje, and child class of Panel1 it's Panel2 which extends Panel1, i put main method in Panel is this problem? how i can correct code to work.

```
package nasleđivanje;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Nasleđivanje{

protected JFrame okvir;
protected JPanel prviPanel;
protected JTextArea txtPolje;

protected void kreirajOkvir(){

    okvir=new JFrame();
    okvir.setSize(500, 400);
    okvir.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    okvir.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    prviPanel=new JPanel();
    prviPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    txtPolje=new JTextArea();

    prviPanel.add(txtPolje,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    okvir.add(prviPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

   }
}

class Panel1 extends Nasleđivanje {

    protected JButton dugme1,dugme2;

    public void kreirajPanel(){

    dugme1=new JButton("Text 1");
    dugme1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            txtPolje.setText("Kliknuli ste na prvo dugme");
        }
    });

    dugme2=new JButton("Text 2");
    dugme2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            txtPolje.setText("Kliknuli ste na drugo dugme");
        }
    });

    prviPanel.add(dugme1,BorderLayout.WEST);
    prviPanel.add(dugme2, BorderLayout.WEST);
           }
 }

   class Panel2 extends Panel1{

protected JButton dugme3,dugme4;


       public void kreirajPanel(){

    dugme3=new JButton("Promeni boju");
    dugme3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            prviPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    });

    dugme4=new JButton("Izlaz");
    dugme4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    prviPanel.add(dugme3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    prviPanel.add(dugme4,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   }

     public void pokreniGUI(){
    okvir.setVisible(true);
       }


public Panel2(){

    super.kreirajOkvir();
    this.kreirajPanel();
    super.kreirajPanel();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Panel2 start=new Panel2();
    start.pokreniGUI();

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have multiple classes in one file. DO NOT DO THAT. One class (and its private classes) per file ONLY.

Because you did this, your main class does not have the main method in it. Your main method is part of the Panel2 class because of its location. Put your main method in the main class and separate out your classes into separate files.

Comment: (except if you're using inner classes, which is another topic ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer Which is what I mean by "private classes"... same idea.

Comment: Inner classes can be private ;), but I'm just being picky ;)

Comment: Yes, you are. Of course, "inner classes" is the correct term. Private class is me forgetting the term "inner classes", lol

Answer (score 1):

> Compiler don't see main method and I can't run program,

Main method acts as the entry point for your program and every class in Java are allowed to have its own `main()` method. Hence, if you have multiple classes in your project and when you run the project, it will run from the `main()` method of the main class being set for your project.

If you are running your project,

1) Ensure there is a main method in the main class or

2) Change the main class in your project and ensure that class contains a main method.

Comment: how to change main in my project

Comment: @GlacialMan If you are using an IDE an not a notepad, explore in the options for your class or project, there you can change it. It is hard to direct you since I do not know what IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Normally an IDE will configure running an application by passing the name of the `public` class to the `java` interpreter.  Assuming this, yes, there is no `main` method in your `public` class `Nasleđivanje`.  You can move `main` there as a simple solution.

Or, you can configure your IDE to run `Panel2` instead of `Nasleđivanje`.  Java will let you run a proper `main` method even if the enclosing class isn't `public`.